# uninitialized constant SOCKSSocket

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I am running ruby 1.9.3 on a linux box.  I would like to use SOCKSSocket, however, I continue to run into the following error:

uninitialized constant SOCKSSocket

simple test using IRB

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'resolv-replace'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> SOCKSSocket
NameError: uninitialized constant SOCKSSocket
    from (irb):2
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

here is the source code directly from resolv-replace.rb

```
class SOCKSSocket < TCPSocket
  # :stopdoc:
  alias original_resolv_initialize initialize
  # :startdoc:
  def initialize(host, serv)
    original_resolv_initialize(IPSocket.getaddress(host), port)
  end
end if defined? SOCKSSocket
```

I can't help but think that I need to install some dependency needed to enable socks or something.  Anything would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems the configure script does not have --enable-socks as part of it's list of valid options and that is the reason for the WARNING: unrecognized options ...

I did not track down how to add --enable-socks to the list of valid options, however, I did rig the script.

Edit: configure

find the section: Initialize some vars... and add enable_option_checking=no

```
# Initialize some variables set by options.
enable_option_checking=no
```

Now, run:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-socks
make
sudo make install

>ruby --version => 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-linux]
```

then, try it out in irb

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'socket'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'resolv-replace'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> SOCKSSocket
=> SOCKSSocket
irb(main):004:0>
```

I haven't done anything using SOCKSSocket yet, however, at least now it looks like I have it accessible to my code.  Also, I assume there is some ENV var to disable option checking or a better way around it.  I just did not track that down.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

SOCKSSocket appears to be an optional component of ruby.  That's why
resolv-replace only monkey-patches the class if it already exists.

As an illustration, 'net/ftp' defines the following method:

```
def open_socket(host, port)
  if defined? SOCKSSocket and ENV["SOCKS_SERVER"]
    @passive = true
    return SOCKSSocket.open(host, port)
  else
    return TCPSocket.open(host, port)
  end
end
```

Perhaps you could do something similar (i.e. create a SOCKS socket if
you have SOCKS enabled, otherwise create a boring old TCP socket).

And if you really need the proxy behaviour, a quick google search
revealed the following gem: http://socksify.rubyforge.org/ which
might be useful.