# How to connect to FTP via SOCKS5 proxy with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, proxy, ftp, socks

I'm trying to connect to FTP via SOCKS5 proxy using ruby's library `Net::FTP`. Documentation says to set env variable `SOCKS_SERVER` in order to connect through proxy (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-connect), but it seems like it does not work.

Code I'm running is this:

```
irb(main):054:0> ftp = Net::FTP.new
=> #<Net::FTP:0x007efd08c73768 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x007efd08c73718>, @binary=true, @passive=true, @debug_mode=false, @resume=false, @sock=#<Net::FTP::NullSocket:0x007efd08c736f0>, @logged_in=false, @open_timeout=nil, @read_timeout=60>
irb(main):056:0> ENV['SOCKS_SERVER'] = 'host:port'
=> "host:port"
irb(main):055:0> ftp.connect('test.rebex.net')
=> nil
irb(main):057:0> ftp.login('demo', 'password')
=> true
irb(main):058:0> ftp.ls
=> ["10-27-15  03:46PM       <DIR>          pub", "04-08-14  03:09PM                  403 readme.txt"]
```

When I look to proxy logs I can not see any requests going through.

What I'm doing wrong or does anybody have an example how to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean 'it seems like it does not work'? What error message are you getting? Can you include the code you're using, what you're expected it to do, and what it is doing, so that there's a better chance that someone can help you out?

Comment: Does the `SOCKS_SERVER` environment variable need to be set _before_ you call `ftp.connect()`?

Comment: Copy paste error.. @Castaglia thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: From the Ruby [Net::FTP source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/net/ftp.rb#L335), there's a check to see if `SOCKSSocket` is supported, in addition to the `SOCKS_SERVER` env var check.  And [this StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9923704/4072843) suggests that your Ruby _might_ not be built with SOCKS support.

Answer (score 0):

If your on Windows computer you'll need to use `dress_socks` gem and Monkeypath:

```rb
$socks_server = '127.0.0.1'
$socks_port   = '9090'
require 'dress_socks' 

class Net::FTP 
  def open_socket(host, port) # :nodoc:
    # puts "opening socket #{@host}:#{port}"
    return DressSocks::Socket.new(@host, port, 
        socks_server: $socks_server, socks_port: $socks_port)
  end
end
```